# Given a triangle $ABC$, how do we prove that the triangle $(\lambda A)(\lambda B)(\lambda C)$ has the same angles?

Tags: geometry

I have been thinking this for a while and tried to prove it with elementary tools (basic euclidean geometry, I must admit that my knowledge of euclidean geometry is not so high) without success. When I try to answer questions like:

- Why any triangle with sides $\lambda A, \lambda B, \lambda C$ has the same angles of the triangle with sides $A,B,C$, for any $\lambda>0$?
- Why any triangle with sides $A+\lambda,B+\lambda, C+\lambda$ doesn't have the same angles of the triangle of sides $A,B,C$, for any $\lambda >0$?

It seems that the notion of angle I have is "inexistent": Looking at the constructed line segments, it doesn't seem there is something I could use to prove that. It seems I need "something else".

Comment: Because the first two are similar triangles, and the second two are not similar triangles?

Comment: Take the sides $A$ and $B$, and produce/shrink them to have lengths $\lambda A, \lambda B$. Then connect the endpoints. By similarity, the third side is $\lambda C$. Since triangles with equal sides are congruent this is the triangle in question. But one of its angles coincides with the one between $A$ and $B$ by construction, hence is equal to it. Proof for the other two angles is analogous.

Comment: Use the Law of Cosines.